# Alert makes app crash on phone but not in simulator

Tags: swift

I am using the following function to display an alert with an "ok" and a "cancel" Button:

```
func displayModalDialog(#title: String, message: String, yesHandler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)?, noHandler: ((UIAlertAction!) -> Void)?) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: noHandler))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This function is part of view controller which is the parent class of most view controllers in my app. When I start my app in the Simulator everything works fine and the alert is displayed with the specified parameters. However when I try to run it on a phone (4s with iOS7 and 5 with iOS8 tested) it crashes on the line:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
```

giving me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Using exceptionBreakpoints did not reveal any additional information.

Hope anyone has help - thanks!